# AjaxToolKit CalendarExtender Problems

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

In my Summary page, I have two CalendarExtender controls to enable someone to select Start Date and End Date for database queries.

In the head of my Summary.aspx page, I have the following declarations:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
<%@ Page Title="ACP Sheet Metal - Summary" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Summary.aspx.cs" Inherits="AcpSheetMetal.Summary" UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>
```

For the page itself, I have a `ToolkitScriptManager`, two (2) `TextBox` controls, two `CalendarExtender` controls, and a `GridView` control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calExStartDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" OnClientShown="ChangeCalendarView" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calExEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" OnClientShown="ChangeCalendarView" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" DaysModeTitleFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" DefaultView="Months" Enabled="True" TodaysDateFormat="MMMM dd, yyyy" />
<asp:GridView ID="summaryGridView" runat="server" />
```

In the `Page_Load` event in the C# code, I have placed the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MasterPage = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    calExEndDate.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
    calExStartDate.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
  }
}
```

So, why are my Calendar controls not working? There are no values in the calendars and the language appears to be Spanish.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language is Spanish and I believe it's so because your `UICulture` is `UICulture="es"` (ESpañol)  and `Culture="es-MX"` (Español México).

See this line on your markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="ACP Sheet Metal - Summary" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Summary.aspx.cs" Inherits="AcpSheetMetal.Summary" UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

The rest of your markup looks okay to me.

Comment: That's what all of the examples I've found online say to use. What should I change it to? Even your example shows `UICulture="es" Culture="ex-MX"`. It must be hard for us to get English! :)

Comment: @jp2code: You are safe removing those 2 pieces (UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX") from your page. It should use the default culture on the server (English on your case)

Comment: OK, now I have English. For yet another +1 and for the marked answer, can you tell me why my Calendar Control has no dates inside it?

Comment: @jp2code: I am honestly not sure about the reason, but I would remove from code behind:  `calExEndDate.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;`and  `calExStartDate.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;` and from the `ToolscriptManager` markup: `EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true"` and `EnableScriptLocalization="true"` to see what effect it has. I used the `AjaxControlToolkit` long, long time ago (I prefer the jQuery UI now).

Comment: How do you make the jQuery call? :)

Comment: @jp2code: Take a look at this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ all you need to do is include the jQuery javascript library on your aspx page. I can provide a full working example for your reference but not right now as I am on my way out, unfortunately. If you still haven't figured out how to do it with jQuery by the time I get home, I will provide the example for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just add EnableScriptGlobalization="true" in your ScriptManager like this: